# What can be approaches(algorithms) to solve the Atmospheric Turbulation problem?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

## Problem:

Atmospheric turbulation problem occurs due to foze,temperature variations, looking at to long distances with camera. There is a problem sample below

## Example:

[image]

## What I tried so far:

1. When I searched, I found [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6471221) which suggests to use
   Dual Tree Complex Wavelet Transform(DTCWT). I followed through the
   article and it seems like a good way to apply. Then I found [this
   implementation](https://github.com/rjw57/dtcwt) of the article in python code. I have run it and
   seen the results but not as expected well.
2. I have simply took the average of some frames(let say 10), and get a result. I did it because the shaking pixels will be mostly true ones at any time. My results seems not bad after averaging.

## What I need:

After searching much I am sure that this solution needs more frame to get one good frame. To do that I need a good image fusion algorithm.

I kindly request that you can suggest me any algorithm or any approaches I can try and go throuh to solve problem.

***Note:** I am familiar with OpenCV and C++ so priority is on these.*

Comment: ok, so you want to use many frames. Do you have any assumptions/limitations for the camera motion? You could give moving-camera-background modeling a try. Typically they use optical flow to overcome/correct camera/object motion between frames

Comment: @Micka camera will be stable for now no movement no shaking, camera is constant. I thought about optical flow but how exactly can be used on this? Also moving objects on the frame ignored for now.

Comment: so what exactly are you looking for when you are asking for "image fusion"?

Comment: For example how can I use 10 distorted frame samples to get one good frame? How can I find lucky pixels, how can I make roi aligment etc.? These are not included in image fusion?

Comment: I think the question is too broad. You already tried the simple stuff (averaging => you could try median in addition). You could try keypoint matching or optical flow and try to find some kind of pattern how pixels move (sinus waves?). Maybe you can find some theoretical solution (physical explanation for the pixel motion and the physical pattern) and then you'll know what kind of features you have to detect in the image. Probably no one else here has experience in that domain, so it will be up to you to make experiments.

Comment: @Micka 1- I chose lucky frames(more sharpen frames) by using laplacian method with a reference limitation. 2- I took the average of first 10 frames(after that next frames included one frame of 10 array subtracted) and averaging cont,nues like that 3- I applied wiener flter to sharpen 4- I lastly applied CLAHE  to result.. My problem is about averaging, its simple and not appropriate. I am stuck on 2nd step. I ll try to dig on thanks for advises

Comment: Generally speaking, finding a good estimation algorithm implies first to get a model of the distortion brought by turbulation. Averaging is optimal only if distortion can be modeled by an additive noise, which doesn't seem to be the case here.